# How to write complex security rules for firestore

Tags: firebase, server, google-cloud-firestore, backend

I want to develop a board game where 2 players play online and it is a turn based game.

I thought of using firebase's firestore as a backend for my app, this requires me to write all queries and paths to my database on the client app.

Well, that was okay when the requirements were to store a list of authenticated users in the firestore database, and writing the security rules for that is easy.

The problem arises when I want to write security rules for the gameplay writes and reads, because, as you know as I said all the game logic and server writes and reads are written on client side and therefore are insecure.

The problem is that in this case I must write the game logic inside the database rules page on firebase console, which is inconvenient for some reasons:

1. The rules(i.e. game logic) are complex so verifying the incoming request inside the rules page before making this request able to write to the database will be a pain and putting all this verification code inside the database rules page (which is only 1 and can't be composed of multiple files) will make code messy instantly
2. there will be duplication of rules on the client app and on the database rules page

So is there a way to overcome this problem?

note: I prefer not to use cloud functions if this is possible

**Update**:

For example, say the user wants to make a move on the board, how can I make sure that the move is valid using security rules? this will require sending the game state information in the request, and then making the very long game business rules verification of the move inside the database rules page, which is inconvenient

Comment: You may be looking at this the wrong way. Firebase Rules govern what can or cannot be read/written to Firebase and most importantly; *Firebase Rules are not filters*. What you're asking is a LOGIC question, not a Rules question. Whether a chess piece can move one square forward to two is governed by logic in your app. Rules are in place to protect data integrity, not to make logic decisions. They are part of the big picture though but your gameplay rely's on code, not Firebase. Unfortunately, this question is broad and can't really be answered here on SO as SO is for code specific issues.

Comment: @Jay thanks for your comment, You almost answered my question, where can I put this logic if not in the database rules? Are cloud functions the only solution for this? Because you know you can't rely on code written in client app

Comment: You can 100% rely on the code in your app to make logic decisions. Not sure why you would think otherwise. Firebase Rules ensure the integrity of the *data* (not code). If the user selects their pawn chess piece and moves it to the right, the logic in your code should disallow that. That's very different than once it's been moved, storing where it moved to.

Comment: @Jay To make my self clear, if the user somehow modifies the code to accept an invalid move, and sends this to my database, then if I am not verifying the info in security rules before writing them to the db, then I will have invalid info written to my db, did you get me now on what I mean by I can't rely on integrity of request coming from code on client app? Please if you can help

Comment: If you're enabling users to modify the code, that's an issue in itself. Again though, this question is too broad for SO and not related to a specific coding question. I would suggest heading over the the firebase googlegroups as that is more of a discussion type forum and not coding specific.

Comment: @Jay "If you're enabling users to modify the code" thats not what I mean, I mean if the user reverse-engineered the compiled apk and somehow was able to modify the code and run a modified version of my app that writes wrong data to my database, then this would cause problems, and security rules can't solve this without making the security rules messy

Comment: If you need total control over the execution of the code, the only safe place to do that is on the backend.  Never trust client code.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ok that is what I expected, so the only solution without using cloud functions is running my own server, because verifying the logic of the write requests inside the security rules is not achievable, please correct me if I am wrong